# Moving vertical line when hovering over the chart using chart.js in v2.9.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm using a code that was used to work before. Now it is not working in the new version v2.9.4. I'm giving the old code below:

```js
Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.line;
Chart.controllers.LineWithLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
   draw: function(ease) {
      Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);

      if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
         var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
             ctx = this.chart.ctx,
             x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
             topY = this.chart.legend.bottom,
             bottomY = this.chart.chartArea.bottom;

         // draw line
         ctx.save();
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
         ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
         ctx.lineWidth = 2;
         ctx.strokeStyle = '#07C';
         ctx.stroke();
         ctx.restore();
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: whats the error

Comment: @Seabizkit there is no error. It just isn't working on v2.9.2. I want it like this demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/dbyze2ga/658/

Comment: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4495

Comment: you need to look at how to do this for version 2, what you have is a feature of version 1, version 2 its done in a different way... so just google it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023773/chart-js-what-is-the-new-syntax-for-extending should help

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following to the chart `options`:

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'x',
    intersect: false
  },
  ...
```

> Please consult [Tooltip Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-configuration) and [Interaction Modes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#interaction-modes) from Chart.js documentation.

```js
Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.line;
Chart.controllers.LineWithLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function(ease) {
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
    if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
      var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
        ctx = this.chart.ctx,
        x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
        topY = this.chart.legend.bottom,
        bottomY = this.chart.chartArea.bottom;
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
      ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
      ctx.lineWidth = 2;
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#07C';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

new Chart("chart", {
  type: 'LineWithLine',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'x',
      intersect: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: I want it to use it like this-> http://jsfiddle.net/dbyze2ga/658/

Comment: OK, I got the point and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. But I need the line all the time. on the canvas where ever I hover. In this demo, it just only appears when I just only hover on the ticks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is two years old. Nowadays, we can achieve this using `plugins` and hook calls in this case `beforeTooltipDraw` to capture the `tooltip.caretX`. Also we can use the build-in [interaction option](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html) to achieve this.

```js
const $chart = document.getElementById('chart')

const plugin = {
    id: 'verticalLiner',
    afterInit: (chart, args, opts) => {
      chart.verticalLiner = {}
    },
    afterEvent: (chart, args, options) => {
        const {inChartArea} = args
        chart.verticalLiner = {draw: inChartArea}
    },
    beforeTooltipDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
        const {draw} = chart.verticalLiner
        if (!draw) return

        const {ctx} = chart
        const {top, bottom} = chart.chartArea
        const {tooltip} = args
        const x = tooltip?.caretX
        if (!x) return

        ctx.save()
        
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(x, top)
        ctx.lineTo(x, bottom)
        ctx.stroke()
        
        ctx.restore()
    }
}

const data = {
  labels: ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [12, 3, 2, 1, 8, 8, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 1]
  }]
}

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    plugins: {
      verticalLiner: {}
    }
  },
  plugins: [plugin]
}

const chart = new Chart($chart, options)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 98vw; height:180px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
```